# Continuity equation in cosmology in terms of derivatives of redshift

Tags: homework-and-exercises, cosmology, space-expansion, redshift

I was trying to write this equation 
$$\dot{\rho}+3\frac{\dot{a}}{a}\rho_{m}=-\frac{\dot{\Lambda (t)}}{8\pi G}$$ 
as
$$(1+z)^{3}\frac{d}{dz}(\frac{\rho_{m}(z)}   {(1+z)^{3}})=-\frac{1}{8\pi G}\frac{d\Lambda(z)}{dz}$$

I know that the first equation can be writed as $$\dot{\rho}_{m}+3\frac{\dot{a}}{a}\rho_{m}=\frac{1}{a^{3}}
\frac{d}{dt}(a^{3}\rho_{m})=-\frac{1}{8\pi G}\frac{d\Lambda(t)}{dt}$$ 
And using the fact $a(t)=(1+z(t))^{-1}$. I obtain

$$ (1+z)^{3}\frac{d}{dt}(\frac{\rho_{m}(z)}   {(1+z)^{3}})=-\frac{1}{8\pi G}\frac{d\Lambda(t)}{dt}$$
The problem is, how can I change the derivative with respect the cosmic time with the deriviative with respect z? Is this trivial?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

$$\frac{d}{dt} = \frac{d}{dz}\frac{dz}{da}\frac{da}{dt}=\frac{d}{dz}-a^{-2}\dot{a}$$

for 
$$a^{-3}\frac{d}{dt}(a^{3}\rho_{m})=-\frac{1}{8\pi G}\frac{d\Lambda(t)}{dt}$$

we can use

$$\frac{d\Lambda}{dt} = \frac{d\Lambda}{dz}\frac{dz}{da}\frac{da}{dt}=\frac{d\Lambda}{dz}-a^{-2}\dot{a}$$

and for $k = a^3\rho_m$

$$\frac{dk}{dt} = \frac{dk}{dz}\frac{dz}{da}\frac{da}{dt}=\frac{dk}{dz}-a^{-2}\dot{a}$$

So we can write

$$a^{-3}\frac{d}{dz}(a^{3}\rho_{m})-a^{-2}\dot{a}=-\frac{-a^{-2}\dot{a}}{8\pi G}\frac{d\Lambda(t)}{dz}$$

or

$$a^{-3}\frac{d}{dz}(a^{3}\rho_{m})=-\frac{1}{8\pi G}\frac{d\Lambda(t)}{dz}$$